# Can snapToOffsets be made to work with React-Native web export?

Tags: react-native, web, progressive-web-apps

One of the outputs of my react-native project is a PWA, however, while snapToOffsets works on iOS and Android export, it doesn't work with web export.

I've confirmed this with chrome, safari, and by deploying to vercel and running as a PWA on iOS (So Safari iOS).

It can also be seen in this snack:
https://snack.expo.dev/SyWXFqDAB?platform=web

While I haven't tried pageEnabled or snapToInterval, my snapping points are irregularly spaced, so these wouldn't work.

Is there a way to make this work?
Or is their an alternative approach?

Thanks! Dale.